# What does struct.calcsize('P') exactly mean?

Tags: python

I stumbled upon this while going through installation instructions of scikit-learn.
To check the architecture of your system, whether it is 32 or 64 bit

What does it exactly mean? What does P format specifier mean? How does it differ in a 32 bit system and a 64 bit system.

What happens when I put different specifiers?

Comment: Read the docs https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/struct.html — `void *`

Comment: @Dunes It calculates the size of byte object returned pack. Which represents the byte object with the fmt string 'P'. What does capital 'P' stand for. I can't find it.

Comment: @Dunes Well, I tried struct.pack('P', 'A') and it said it wants an integer, so I am guessing 'P' is for an INT.

Now, the size is coming down to be 4 Bytes. So its using 4 bytes for storing an integer. Multiplying by 8 gives us 32 bits.

Is this logic correct?

Comment: @Dunes Can you please confirm?

Comment: The meaning of 'P' is right there in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/struct.html#format-characters): `C type: void *; Python type: integer` (plus footnote 5 below the table).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`struct` is a module for packing and unpacking data to and from C representations. `P` represents `void *` (a generic pointer). On 32-bit systems a pointer is 4 bytes, and on a 64-bit system a pointer requires 8 bytes. `struct.calcsize('P')` calculates the number of bytes required to store a single pointer -- returning 4 on a 32-bit system and 8 on a 64-bit system.